# Reading Data Into Buffer To Access From JavaScript From C

Tags: javascript, c, buffer, webassembly

I'm going through the WASM documentation on MDN and I was interested in understanding how to access struct data in C from JavaScript.

In [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), I can see the following where I need to copy data into a C buffer and somehow access that buffer from the JS side.

I'm not sure how to go about implementing the `...read data into buffer` part of the docuumentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a view to the memory's buffer, and then copy the bytes (or access the bytes directly from the view). Using a `DataView` (endianness can be chosen) is better then an `ArrayBuffer` (uses the platform's endianness), because not every platform that runs JavaScript uses little [endian](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Endianness), but WebAssembly stores its integers [always in little endian](https://webassembly.org/docs/portability/):

```
// have 'memory' (the instance's memory) and 'offset' (number)

// create a view to the whole memory
let view = new DataView(memory.buffer, 0, memory.byteLength);

// read a little endian 32 bit unsigned int
let id = view.getUint32(offset, true);

// log
console.log(id);
```

You can always copy the data into another DataView and store it "for later". There are certain things to conciser when reading from the memory's buffer. For example, if the memory grows subsequently, your  view might point to the old memory's buffer, and so you will read from/write to obsolete buffer.

Docs: [DataView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView), DataView.[getUint32](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getUint32).

Comment: Here, is memory.buffer just a memory address? So, for instance, let's say I wanted to copy an array of 10 ints called arr would memory.buffer the address of arr[0] and byteLength be 40 bytes (4bytes * 10)? Want to make sure I'm thinking about this correctly.

Comment: The buffer of a WebAssembly.Memory is an ArrayBuffer or SharedArrayBuffer, depending of is the memory shared or not. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/Memory/buffer